# How are data assimilation and machine learning different?

Tags: machine-learning

This might seem like a really silly question, however I have not been able to find any answers to it on the internet.

From my rough understanding of data assimilation, it combines data with numerical models by having weights on the adjustment initial condition parameters? That sounds really similar to what machine learning/neural network does.

What are the distinct differences?